# how to save canvas object position and reload them in UWP c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, uwp, savefiledialog

I made a "Dodge Game" that adds charaters to a canvas, and a button "save".
When i press the "Save: button, I want to save all the objects location, game settings ( timer current form),etc'.
Then i would like to make a button that reload the game (the canvas with the save products) and run from "the same spot".
I need a way to save and upload the game.

I will appriciate every single help / direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you want. Here are some guidelines that could help.

### 1. Game State Objects

Represent your game state using entities (classes that represents data).

Example:

```cs
public class GameState
{
   public CharacterData[] Characters { get; set; }
   public TimeSpan GameTime { get; set; }
}

public class CharacterData
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double PositionX { get; set; }
   public double PositionY { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Serialization

Once you have a class that represents your game state, you can use serialization to convert that object and its content to a single string.
There are various serialization formats. JSON and XML are popular ones.

Example using [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
// ...
GameState myState;
// ...
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myState);
```

### 3. Write File

Once your data is serialized, you can easily write it in a file.

Example:

```cs
StorageFile sampleFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, jsonString));
```

---

At this point, you have the steps to save your game state.

Next steps are about going from the file back to a game state.

---

### 4. Read File

First step is to read the file.

Example:

```cs
StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
var fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

### 5. Deserialization

Once you have the raw file content, you need to parse it to re-obtain a `GameState` object.
Since we used JSON serialization, we want to do the opposite and do JSON deserialization.

Example (again using System.Text.Json):

```cs
GameState gameState = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameState>(fileContent);
```

### Next Steps

1. You need to customize the `GameState` object structure based on your actual needs (so that all information is captured).
2. You need to instantiate a `GameState` based on your current implementation (when you save the game).
3. You need to be able to bootstrap your game based on a `GameState` object (put the objects in the canvas when you load the game).